# RSA public key encrypts ASCII value to 0, how to decrypt?

Tags: encryption, rsa

I've decided to learn about RSA encryption since learning about the vernal cipher in a comp sci lecture.
I grasp the idea behind RSA (it's very clever), however while trying to write my own C program to encrypt and decrypt a string of characters I have run into a few problems.

I am encrypting each character's ASCII value using the public key then decrypting the cipher text. However, I have found that sometimes the public key I have created will encrypt an ASCII value to 0, then there is no way to decrypt it as 0^anything = 0. 
I surely must be wrong here as binary can be encrypted/decrypted using RSA.

E.g.

- p = 3
- q = 5
- N = 15 (p*q)
- m = (p-1)(q-1) = 8
- e = 7 (coprime to m)
- d = 7 (7d(mod8) = 1 ... Before people have a go, I am only using 7 because it's convenient for this example (not for a secure encryption)

Now take the char "T" (ASCII value 84)

Run the encryption, the cipher text is = 0

0^7 (mod 8) = 0 ... not 84!

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The most obvious problem is that you're encrypting a string directly with RSA. You should encrypt a key for a symmetric cypher and use that symmetric cypher to encrypt the message. You should also use correct padding.

Comment: Also you can only apply RSA to integers 0<=i<N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSA encryption is limited to encrypting positive numbers in the range 1 to (p*q)-1, which are not multiples of p or q.  In practical applications, p*q will generally be much bigger than the largest message to be encrypted, and messages will be padded with random bits to fill up the range 1 to (p*q)-1.  While it's theoretically possible that the random padding chosen for a message might cause it to be a multiple of p or q, in practice the only way that can happen is if there is something severely wrong with the random number generator.

In "toy applications", however, problematic values represent a much larger portion of the possible message space.  Even if you chose p and q to be large enough that the p*q was larger than your message (e.g. 13 and 17) there would still be many possible message values that would fail (e.g. 65 or 85).  I would suggest 13 and 17 as reasonable values to use for demonstration purposes, with the caveat that not all message values will work.

Comment: hello, this maybe outdated thread, but i facing similar problem, it is also for learning application only.. instead of P and Q too small, in my case, it is too big, i have N = 16351, and because of that, the chiper result is too big up to 16 bit. 
and now when i try to convert the cipher(int) into ascii, it is resulting blank, because the value is outside range of ascii.. what to do for this case?
very appreciated if you still notice my question. Thanks :)

Comment: RSA is generally used to either encrypt binary encryption keys or hash values which are smaller than the RSA key have padding added; the ciphertext or signature will then be the size of the RSA key that was used, i.e. bigger than the encryption key or hash value that was fed into the RSA algorithm.

Comment: yes yes, i know a bit about the concept, but i dont really understand the implementation. like i told you before, i have N = 16351, and then i tried to encrypt 'a' by its ascii value, and get the result 13368. and what next after i got this value? what should i returning? i want to return the cipher as char also, but cant get the anything because it is outside the range of ascii. even if i split it into 2 8bit, it still outside ascii range
what should i do with the result of encryption calculation?

Comment: @hphp: You need to keep the cipher text as a number in some form while it's delivered to someone with the other half of the key.  Using the other half of the key on the number will yield the pre-encryption value.  For security, you should pad the value being encrypted with 01 followed by some arbitrary bits.  So instead of encrypting 97 (0x0061), you'd encrypt e.g. 0x1B61).  Then after decryption yields 0x1B61, you'd examine the last two bits which should be 0x61.  The bits should be random when encrypting, and should be included with the encrypted message when signing.

Comment: oooh so i dont need to change back the cipher to ascii? what form usually/commonly used to hide the number? or maybe do you have any suggestion, just for to understanding the rsa implementation? for learning

Comment: by pad the value with some arbitrary bits, do you mean like salt?

Comment: Suppose that one was using a public exponent of 3, and some secret message m, m³ was congruent to 8000 mod 16351.  How hard would it be for an attacker to figure out the value of m?

Comment: okay okay i think i get it now, i'll try to enhance my code then.. thanks @supercat.. even after 11 years, you still have superanswer